# Subscribing twice to same observable causing expression changed after checked error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to subscribe to the same observable twice in my component view:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">
    Is Loading
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!(isLoading$ | async)">
    Is Not Loading
</ng-container>
```

This is the relevant parts of the .ts file for the same component:

```
isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoading$ = this.loadingService.loading$;
    }
```

This is the Loading Service:

```
export class LoadingService {
  
  private loadingSource: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  private loadingCount = 0;
  public loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.loadingSource.asObservable();

  private isLoading(): boolean {
    return this.loadingCount > 0;
  }

  public startLoad() {
    this.loadingCount++;
    this.loadingSource.next(this.isLoading());  
  }

  public endLoad() {
    this.loadingCount--;
    this.loadingSource.next(this.isLoading());
  }
}
```

And the Loading Interceptor that sets the values in the Loading Service:

```
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loadingService.startLoad();
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        share(),
        finalize(() => {
          this.loadingService.endLoad();
        })
      );
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I subscribe to the observable twice using the async pipe as I have done above, I receive the Expression Changed After Checked which reads:

*NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100*

Any ideas?

Comment: move it to AfterViewInit() {
        this.isLoading$ = this.loadingService.loading$;
    }

Comment: Tried this but the same error persists

Comment: have you tried combining in one? <ng-container *ngIf="(isLoading$ | async) as loading">{{ loading ? 'Is Loading' : ' Is Not Loading' }}</ng-container>

Comment: I need both ng-container elements to be there so two different code blocks are added depending on whether it's loading or not so that wouldn't work either unfortunately!

Comment: can you create stackblitz to repro?

Comment: I can't I'm afraid as it's work related

Comment: you can add your ng-container in the combined condition(above shared) to prevent multiple subscription in template.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes because your value is updated before your first value updates your DOM. Please read this article for more info [Click here](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100.)

To fix this issue you can call your  endLoad() in ngOnInit() And
I think your intercept() #service finalizes() your value and set your Loading to false before ViewInit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change `ReplaySubject(1)` to `BehaviorSubject`

**service**

```
export class LoadingService {

  private loadingSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.loadingSource.asObservable();

  private isLoading(): boolean {
    return this.loadingSource.value;
  }

  public startLoad() {
    this.loadingSource.next(true);
  }

  public endLoad() {
    this.loadingSource.next(false);
  }
}
```

**ts**

```
isLoading(): boolean {
    return this.loadingService.isLoading;
}

ngOnInit(){ }
```

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
    Is Loading
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
    Is Not Loading
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Eddy. The purpose of having the loading count is for concurrency. There may be several pieces of data being loaded from the backend so I need to keep track of how many are active at any given time. Only once all http requests have been completed do I want to stop the loading spinner

Comment: like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f5vuda